# Sort by a different index's values

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Given two indexes, I'm trying to sort the first based on values of the second.

For example, Index 1 ('Products') has fields id, name. Index 2 ('Prices') has fields id, price.

Struggling to figure out how to sort 'Products' by the 'Prices'.price, assuming the ids match. Reason for this quest is that hypothetically the 'Products' index becomes very large (with duplicate ids), and updating all documents becomes expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch is a document based store, rather than a column based store. What you're looking for is a way to JOIN the two indices, however this is not supported in Elasticsearch. The 'Elasticsearch way' of storing these documents is to have 1 index that contains all relevant data. If you're worried about update procedures taking very long, look into creating an index with an Alias. When you need to do a major update, do it to a new index and only when you're done switch the alias target to the new index, this will allow you to update you data seamlessly